# Opening Visual Studio 2005 files with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

We have MS Reporting Services .sln files that we open with Visual Studio 2005. We are moving to Visual Studio 2015. When trying to open the .sln files with Visual Studio 2015 we get the following:

[image: One way upgrade]

We choose to upgrade and get the upgrade report that reports it was successful:

[image: Migration report]

However when trying to open the .sln file after the successful upgrade was reported, it cannot open it.

Any ideas how I can get these files onto the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Reporting Services is not available in Visual Studio 2015 SSDT yet - it is still in Beta, as noted [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx) hence your issues.